# Let O is the circle center and

Tags: geometry

Let O is the circle center and $\overline{AB}$ is the diameter find $\angle{ACE}$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AOE = 60, EOD = 106, and both AOE and EOD are isosceles, so you should be able to take it from there...

Comment: ...sorry i didnt get  your point..can u give me some more hint

Answer (score 1):

The angle $AEC=23°$. Sum of all angles in a triangle is equal to $180°$.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{BD} \;=\; \arc{AB} - \arc{AE} - \arc{ED} \;=\; 180^\circ - 60^\circ - 106^\circ$
- $\widehat{ACE} = \frac{1}{2}(\arc{AE} - \arc{BD}) = \frac{1}{2}(60^\circ - 14^\circ)$